# Svelte handlebars like with-helper?

Tags: svelte

What would be the best way in svelte/sapper to do same thing as handlebars.js with-helper does.
https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent, you just refer to properties directly. If there's a complex expression that you need to use repeatedly, you can encapsulate it as a [computed property](https://svelte.technology/guide#computed-properties).

Comment: Thank you!
Basically i would like to fill components with data like this. But I don't need all data and I have to put components with different data to different places.
`{{#with dog}}<AnimalCard></AnimalCard>{{/with}}`
`{{#with cat}}<AnimalCard></AnimalCard>{{/with}}`

I'm just so used to using handlebars. Would it be totally stupid including handlebars to my sapper project? I'm exporting static site only.

Comment: Pass `dog` and `cat` to the component: `<AnimalCard animal={{dog}}/><AnimalCard animal={{cat}}/>`

Comment: Thanks that's great way to do it!